# "...to have been" or "... to having been"?

Tags: past-perfect

When I help someone and the person thanks me, instead of saying "You're welcome", I want to express that "I am happy that I **was** able to help you", but I want to say it with a much shorter phrase.

I came up with this:

> Happy to have/having been able to help

But I'm not sure which of the usages of *have* after *to* is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the correct forms.

- Happy to have been able to help
- Happy **of** having been able to help

In the same vein, you'll find the following, which you might prefer; "having been" is not used much and possibly not at all in speaking. Here is an [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=happy+of+having%2Chappy+of+having+been%2Cglad+of+having+been&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chappy%20of%20having%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cglad%20of%20having%20been%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chappy%20of%20having%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cglad%20of%20having%20been%3B%2Cc0) showing that "happy of having been" is not found and that "glad of having been" is rare (probably only found in books).

- (I'm) Happy/glad to have been of some help to you.
- (I'm) Happy/glad that I have been of some help to you.

Comment: I don't find _Happy of having been able to help_ at all idiomatic.

Comment: @KateBunting Right, my "more usual" does not reflect reality; would you say that this is hardly said or rather that it is not said at all?

Comment: It is not something a native speaker would naturally say (which is what I meant by _idiomatic_).